# Position divs in row at relative positions, but stack if 2 divs occupy same space

Tags: html, css

If I have a row of relatively positioned divs, that have their `left` attribute set to show a position on a timeline, as per #1 in the image below. If I move the third div's `left` attribute back a little bit, so that it overlaps the second div (as per #2 on the image below), how can I make it so that it moves below the second div and 'stacks', as per #3.

Is this possible with just some clever CSS or will JS need to be involved here to determine if divs are overlapping and set the styling.

[image]

Comment: It can be possible with css and js both.

Comment: You just need to get the `margin-left` or `left`(if absolute) properties for both the `div` and after that set the js condition like `if(B > A){and set the margin-left property of both as equal}`.